# How to do it in a single image- Docker container.Please suggest a simple way as i am new to Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Deployment 1: Assume all the below mentioned applications in point

a) have to be synchronized, during all the transactions.

b)  Use Docker to create a single image, for the below given requirement

c) add all the software’s mentioned below into one image.

•   Java

•   Tomcat

•   Postgres DB

•   Rabbit MQ

•   ALM

AND

Create Java  Hello world program and deploy it to Tomcat server

b)  Assuming Java Hello world is an application which has DB, all the transactions of the application stored in DB have to be captured.

c)Create volumes for DB.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It kind of goes against the very purpose of containerization: one container = one stateless process. DB in containers is usually a bad idea ([although some talented people with a massive engineering team do it](https://eng.uber.com/dockerizing-mysql/)). A DB in the same container as the monolithic service it helps run is... probably not a good idea.

Comment: Instead of running java application in Tomcat, you'd better use Spring-Boot which can embed tomcat. So that you would gain a layer. Moreover, instead of embedding everything in a single image, you'd better use many services (and thus many images) for each part of your application: 1 service for Postgres, 1 service for RabbitMQ, 1 service for your application...